# How to remove external backlinks?

Tags: seo, backlinks

Is there a way to remove or block external backlinks?
There was a drop in the Google results from page 1-2 to page > 8.

I am now looking at the external backlinks and I see now multiple domains that I don't want them to be linked to our website ( sex sites, spi directories, ... ).

Also I have a domain with >1300 links on 1 page ( I see this in Google webmaster tools ).
Can this also be the reason of the drop?

Comment: You should try this : Change your page's address (page's file name), so when Google update directory index, the new page will be indexed and that backlinks will not work.

Comment: What if they link to our domain? `http://www.example.be/`

Comment: You should also track where a visitor is coming from to your site, by code. Then you can redirect unwanted traffics to your site. This is possible in Asp.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that a particular link is negatively affecting your SEO, you can use the [Disavow Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/disavow-links-main). Using this tool, you can ask Google to ignore a particular backlink (or backlinks from a particular domain). Note: You should make sure that these links hold no value before you attempt to disavow them.